# How to hide layers on the "minimap" in the print layout

Tags: qgis, mapping, printing

I am new to QGIS and I am running into a small problem. How do I hide the layers (shapes) showing on the minimap in the print layout? I want them to show on the big map but not on the small one because its to dense and small (see the picture).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on all layers you want to show in the overview map, then toggle [`lock layers`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_map.html#layers), then edit the main map canvas to your liking, then export.

Comment: thnx, that worked like a charm